# I can not start the mariadb.service as soon as I have installed

Tags: database, centos, mariadb, centos7

I have installed mariadb in my CentOS7, "systemctl start mariadb" command does not work. Console out is this --> "`Job for mariadb.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mariadb.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.`"

```
[root@centos ~]# journalctl -xe
 1월 21 00:31:34 centos systemd[1]: mariadb.service failed.
 1월 21 00:31:34 centos polkitd[828]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:3046:129841 (system bus name :1
 1월 21 00:31:53 centos fprintd[3001]: No devices in use, exit
 1월 21 00:32:07 centos polkitd[828]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-process:3087:133140 (system bus name :1.1
 1월 21 00:32:07 centos systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB 10.1.30 database server...
-- Subject: Unit mariadb.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mariadb.service has begun starting up.
 1월 21 00:32:07 centos mysqld[3110]: /usr/sbin/mysqld: error while loading shared libraries: libjemalloc.so.1: cannot o
 1월 21 00:32:07 centos systemd[1]: mariadb.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=127/n/a
 1월 21 00:32:07 centos systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 10.1.30 database server.
-- Subject: Unit mariadb.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mariadb.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
 1월 21 00:32:07 centos systemd[1]: Unit mariadb.service entered failed state.
 1월 21 00:32:07 centos systemd[1]: mariadb.service failed.
 1월 21 00:32:07 centos polkitd[828]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:3087:133140 (system bus name :1
lines 3201-3223/3223 (END)
```

I search long time to solve this problem, i can't find proper solution.
And /var/log/mariadb directory does not exist.

How can i fix this issue? please help me!

(Update)

```
[root@kyun2centos ~]# journalctl -xe|grep 'error'
 1월 23 16:47:12 kyun2centos gnome-settings-[2077]: g_task_return_error: assertion 'error != NULL' failed
 1월 23 20:30:53 kyun2centos mysqld[3754]: /usr/sbin/mysqld: error while loading shared libraries: libjemalloc.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
 1월 23 20:33:11 kyun2centos mysqld[3841]: 2018-01-23 20:33:11 140616961231104 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.user' doesn't exist
 1월 23 20:33:32 kyun2centos mysqld[3964]: 2018-01-23 20:33:32 139707756554496 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.user' doesn't exist
 1월 23 20:42:37 kyun2centos mysqld[4274]: 2018-01-23 20:42:37 140639461787904 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.user' doesn't exist
 1월 23 20:43:12 kyun2centos mysqld[4365]: 2018-01-23 20:43:12 140563394230528 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.user' doesn't exist
 1월 23 20:48:04 kyun2centos mysqld[4553]: 2018-01-23 20:48:04 139807531911424 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.user' doesn't exist
 1월 23 20:50:04 kyun2centos mysqld[4654]: 2018-01-23 20:50:04 140253162838272 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.user' doesn't exist
 1월 23 20:57:30 kyun2centos mysqld[4901]: 2018-01-23 20:57:30 140003728230656 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.user' doesn't exist
```

Comment: See line with `/usr/sbin/mysqld: error while loading shared libraries: libjemalloc.so.1: cannot o`. Provide full-width log to see the whole error message.

Comment: Thanks for reply!
But i don't know how to see the whole error message..

I did drag and copy console massage to editor app, i can see only the message cut after part of width.

Comment: Check this question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/229188/journalctl-how-to-prevent-text-from-truncating-in-terminal/241800

Comment: You can try `yum -y install jemalloc`

Comment: `[ERROR] Could not open mysql.plugin table. Some plugins may be not loaded
[ERROR] Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.servers' doesn't exist
[ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.user' doesn't exist`

Comment: I installed jemalloc and libaio. but still did not work the command "systemctl start mariadb"

Answer (score 0):

It indicate lack library.So run

```
yum install libaio
```

yum would help you install and configure it or you can access the [website](https://pkgs.org/download/libjemalloc.so.1) to download the latest rpm package and install it manually.

Answer (score 0):

*Solution by OP.*

I solve this problem through follow series of commands:

```
yum -y remove mariadb-libs
yum -y remove mariadb mariadb-server
cd /var/lib/ && rm -rfv mysql
yum -y install mariadb mariadb-server
```